# How does Google Vertex AI Matching engine deny list work?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

How does [Vertex matching engine deny list](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/matching-engine/filtering#denylist) work?

Let's say I have a class fruit which will ONLY have deny list tokens (no allow) such as "apple", "mango", etc. How do I filter out "mango" in the query (search all fruits except mango)? I have tried the following method but it does not work as expected:

json:

```json
{"id": "1", "embedding":[0.002792,0.000492], "restricts": [{"namespace": "fruit", "deny": ["mango"]}]}
```

code to query:

```py
deny_namespace = match_service_pb2.Namespace()
deny_namespace.name = "fruit"
deny_namespace.deny_tokens.append("mango")
request.restricts.append(deny_namespace)
```

I have coded this similar to allow list which has worked for me but with deny tokens it does not seem to skip deny tokens even after completely overwriting the index.

Barely changing the field "deny" to "allow" works but "deny" fails to work as expected (it does not throw any error though).

Full code

query

https://gist.github.com/niladridutt/673d4aa2a6225fa47d8aad7398b4cbd1

Proto files-

https://gist.github.com/niladridutt/746833b8d61ec366c8c61de57c784ac4
https://gist.github.com/niladridutt/31e9dc3432e206589729989acddf1225

Comment: Can you provide the full code that you are using?

Comment: @PrajnaRaiT query- https://gist.github.com/niladridutt/673d4aa2a6225fa47d8aad7398b4cbd1

Proto files-
https://gist.github.com/niladridutt/746833b8d61ec366c8c61de57c784ac4
https://gist.github.com/niladridutt/31e9dc3432e206589729989acddf1225

Comment: This issue has been raised in this [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/248534187). However, we cannot provide an ETA at the moment but you can “STAR” the issue to receive automatic updates and give it traction by referring to this [link](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue).

Answer (score 1):

GCP seems to have some problem in their documentation or perhaps this is a bug.
Explicitly adding the value in the "deny" field does not work. What worked for me was placing the same value in the "allow" field and during querying- add the value to be denied in the deny tokens list.